# Purpose of Redux Thunk `([arg(s)]) => dispatch =>`?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

The code below comes from a Udemy course on the MERN stack by Brad Traversy. I'm new to Redux and Redux Thunk and am trying to understand what the purpose of `=> dispatch =>` is. I know it comes from Redux Thunk, which was set up in the Redux store file. I think `dispatch` is being used here in order to dispatch more than one action from this function and read that the `= ([arg(s)]) => dispatch =>` syntax is an example of currying (though that doesn't seem right since with currying each function has one argument).

I'd greatly appreciate any help understanding `=> dispatch =>`.

(Other minor point of confusion: In the course the function `setAlert` is referred to as an action, but I'm not sure that's correct since it contains multiple dispatches of actions.)

```
export const setAlert = (msg, alertType, timeout = 5000) => dispatch => {
  const id = uuidv4();
  dispatch({
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: { msg, alertType, id }
  });

  setTimeout(() => dispatch({ type: REMOVE_ALERT, payload: id }), timeout);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on here:

1) `setAlert` is what is usually called an "action creator". It's a function that returns an action that you can dispatch later.

2) Redux-Thunk is allowing you to use functions of the form `(dispatch) => {}` as actions (in place of the more normal object form `{ type, payload }`)

It might help if you look at them individually before seeing how they combine together:

```
// This is an action creator (a function that returns an action)
// This doesn't use redux thunk, the action is just a simple object.
// Because it's an action creator you can pass in arguments
// Because it's not a thunk you can't control when then dispatch happens
const setAlertActionCreator = (msg, alertType) => {
  const id = uuidv4();
  return {
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: { msg, alertType, id }
  };
};

// You use this as:
dispatch(setAlertActionCreator("msg", "type"));
```

```js
// This is not an action creator it's just an action.
// This IS a redux-thunk action (it's a (dispatch) => {} function not a simple object)
// Because it's not an action creator you can't pass in arguments to get a custom action back
// Because it IS a redux-thunk action you can dispatch more actions later
const setAlertThunk = (dispatch) => {
  setTimeout(() => dispatch({
    type: SET_ALERT,
    payload: {
      message: "fixed message",
      alertType: "fixed alertType",
      id: "fixed id",
    }
  }), 5000);
};

// You use this as:
dispatch(setAlertThunk);
```

```js
// When you combine both patterns you gain the ability
// to both pass in arguments and to create additional dispatches
// as the function runs (in this case dispatching again after a timeout.)
// I won't repeat your code, but will show how you would call it:

dispatch(setAlertActionCreator("msg", "type"));

// ie: you use it the same way as example 1.
```

Comment: Thank you -- is Redux Thunk being used in both of the individual ("on its own") examples? It looks like it's used in the second one since it has `= (dispatch) =>` but since that isn't shown in the first I'm not sure.

Comment: @Natalie Redux Thunk is only being used in the second example. I'll update the comments to make that more clear. The first example is just an action creator, The second example is just a redux thunk action. Your example is a redux thunk action creator.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax `() => dispatch =>` is equivalent to:

```
function response(){
    return function (dispatch){
       //Some code here
    }
}
```

So, basically what you can say is, it is a modern way of writing the same function. `=> dispatch =>` is returning a function that will be executed when the `action` will be invoked.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought that `dispatch` in `=>  dispatch  =>` was an argument and not a function name.

Comment: I do you think that's a function rather than an argument? I found a page that says "Redux Thunk is a middleware that lets you call action creators that return a function instead of an action object. That function **receives the store’s dispatch method**, which is then used to dispatch regular synchronous actions inside the body of the function once the asynchronous operations have completed." https://alligator.io/redux/redux-thunk/

Comment: Also, another source says "Redux will pass two arguments to thunk functions: dispatch, so that they can dispatch new actions if they need to; and getState, so they can access the current state." https://daveceddia.com/what-is-a-thunk/

Comment: Yeah this is wrong. in `() => dispatch =>` dispatch is an argument not the name of the function.

Comment: @david i do agree with you. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

```
=> dispatch =>
```

is nothing but a syntactical sugar over a function returning another function. Since Fat-arrow functions `=>` are used in place of normal functions.

Like

```
function abc(a,b){
return a+b;
}
```

is same as `const abc = (a,b) => a+b ;`

So you dont have to write `return` keyword.

So in your case its the same `=> dispatch =>`  and the one below , its returning an anonymous function with . `dispatch` as its arguement

```
function response(){
    return (dispatch){
       //some code here
    }
}
```

Hope it helps, feel free for doubts